# How do I verify if a birthday is passed or not?

Tags: python, date, if-statement, case

It's similar to my last question. But here I want to know how to know whether or not a person can do something, such as:

If joe is less than 21 he isn't allowed to drink, using the birthday to let you know whether he can or can't. Not using import or calendars, trying to get the hang of it

So far this is what I have come up with.

```
dateStr = input("Today's Date: ")
monthStr, dayStr, yearStr = dateStr.split("/")
months = ["January", "February","March", "April", "May", "June", "July", "August","September","October", "November","December"]
monthStr = months[int(monthStr)- 1]
print ("The converted date is:", monthStr, dayStr+",", yearStr)
print("Joe did NOT have his birthday this year!")
Joe's birthday = True
for chr in dateStr:
  tv = True
  if:
    (i<= 13)
    print("Joe is Not allowed to watch TV.")
  else:
    print("Joe is allowed to watch TV.")
driving = True
if:
  (i<= 16)
    print("Joe is NOT Allowed to drive")
else:
  print("Joe is allowed to drive")
  drinking = True 
if:
  (i<= 21)
    print("Joe is NOT allowed to drink.")
else:
  print("Joes is allowed to drink.")
```

Comment: One might convert the birthday and now into timestamps, take the difference, and compare it to the number of seconds in X years.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I assume this is for an assignment, anyways check out the [datetime](http://docs.python.org/library/datetime.html) module, it is really convenient for generating and comparing dates.

Answer (score 0):

This seems like an assignment question, you should also checkout the [dateutil.parser](http://labix.org/python-dateutil#head-a23e8ae0a661d77b89dfb3476f85b26f0b30349c) which awesomely transforms dates in different formats automatically so you do not have to parse them yourself.